# Is there a use for the "with" function that I can't achieve by "apply", "run", "also" or "let" in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

When would we ever need `with` in Kotlin if we can already use `apply`, `run`, `also` and `let`?

Can anyone give me a clear example?

Comment: I don't know Kotlin, but convenience? The Python `with` statement, for example, can be completely desugared to a loop involving `try` statements and explicit method calls, but it's a lot simpler to read and write code with the `with` statement than without.

Comment: Not everything *useful* has to be *necessary*.

Comment: chepner,, Why did they spend time and effort to invent "with" if we already can use something else? isn't it redundant?

Comment: I think `with(context) { doInContext() }` reads better that `context.run { doInContext() }`. Just reading the words in order in english says exactly what it does.

Comment: Also, with context receivers coming, they could potentially extend `with` to take more parameters in order to bring in more contexts to the scope at the same time. With the other functions, you would have to nest them: `with(context1, context2) {  }` vs `context1.run { context2.run { } }`

Comment: @AhmedEid If you assume that "redundant" means "without any additional connotation", then `with` isn't redundant, just *equivalenent*. If you look at how you would write [semantically equivalent Python code without `with`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement), I don't think you would say that  `with` wasn't worth adding to the language.

Comment: @marstran , then why didn't they just omitted "run" and just keep "with"?

Comment: (Also, my bad for claiming a `with` statement encapsulated a loop; I was thinking about how a `for` loop can be desugared to a `while` loop. I don't think anyone would argue that `for` loops aren't useful, and the desugaring of a `with` statement to the equivalent `try` statement with associated conditionals and method calls is equally undesirable.)

Comment: @AhmedEid Because run has other uses of course. I use `with(context)` when I provide a context, and `process.run` when I want to run something on an object. The point is to make your code readable.

Comment: This question should probably be closed by the way, because it's opinion based.

Comment: @marstran "What can `with` do that `apply`, `run`, `let`, and `also` can't do?" is an objectively answerable question (even if the answer is "nothing").

Answer (score 1):

In most situations, a `with` call can be transformed to a `run` like this:

```
with(foo) {
    // some code ...
}

// is the same as:

foo.run {
    // the same code ...
}
```

`run` and `with` will both return the lambda result, and will use `foo` as the lambda receiver.

However, I can think of one case where this wouldn't work - when `foo` declares its own `run` method that takes a lambda, e.g.

```
// having something like this isn't too uncommon, right?
fun run(x: () -> Unit) {}
```

The lambda type doesn't have to be exactly the same as the scope function `run`. Any function type should work. Then overload resolution wouldn't resolve to the built-in `run`.

You can force the resolution by doing some casts, but using `with` in this case is much better. Don't you agree?

Comment: good answer. Actually the best answer I read yet. But there still a problem. Using the same sense you used, we need a replacement functions for "apply" "also" "let", because  "foo" also can declare those functions.

Comment: But those aren’t popular names for member functions. In fact they would be very vague. Semantically, the need for a member function named “run” is quite common.

Comment: @AhmedEid In addition to what Tenfour04 said, you can replace `apply`, `also` and `let` with the extension function `run` (which can be further replaced with `with`). You just also need to replace usages of `this`/`it`, and potentially return a `this`/`it` at the end of the lambda to match the behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

I don’t think there’s any better example than `with(context)`. Maybe it’s not clear if English isn’t one of your primary languages, but it semantically is translated into English much clearer than `context.run` when the object is being used to produce a result but isn’t the primary actor, so it makes code a little easier to read.

This of course raises the question of why `run` exists. Well, it semantically makes more sense in English when the object is the thing doing the action. In English, the context of an action is what you’re doing something *with*. But if the object is what is directly producing the result, then it is *running* the action.

Also, you can’t do `?.with`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, But don't you think it would be redundant and hard to learn and confusing to use if we made every programming language to cover every semantic situation in English?

Comment: It literally is redundant, but redundant is not necessarily bad. When I first started with Kotlin, I thought it seemed convoluted that there were five different scope functions, but after using it for a couple of years, I find that it makes it easier to review my old code and other people’s code. There are pros and cons. If I were designing the language, I probably would not have included `with`, but since it is there and I’m used to it, I like it now.

Comment: making a language more intuitive by covering multiples semantics is the exact opposite of making it hard to learn. In fact, if we could really have a programming language that does cover every semantic situation, then "programmers would not exists", as you could just write a story and that would be the code.

Comment: @Alex.t , A very good point, but I still don't agree, I still think it will be harder to learn and more confusing to use, because the code will then depend on how much  vocabulary a someone has. Imagine that you're trying to read a source code of another person, but that person uses words that you are not familiar with because you already know other words that do the same tasks and you never faced a problem to a complete any task with just the vocabulary that you have. how would everyone read everyone's Code? Not all people are Poets, and they don't have to be. But still a good point, Thanks.

Comment: `A very good point, but I still don't agree`. You don't have to agree, and that is why this question has no place on SO in the first place, opinions are not programming questions. Btw, you don't need to be a poet, just to know the English language. If you are more versed in another language, there is nobody stopping anybody for making a programming language in that language.